# How to split the column with a Timestamp and extract the hours, minutes and seconds into the separate column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The timestamp in a column looks like this "2020-04-26 17:45:14".
Now I need to extract and insert the "17:45:14" part into another separate column.
How do I do that? I was thinking about using the following code sequence:

SELECT
EXTRACT(____ FROM column)
FROM table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it to a `time` value:

```
select the_column::time as time_only
from the_table
```

Or compliant with the SQL standard:

```
select cast(the_column as time) as time_only
from the_table
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, friend. Gotta check that CAST function.